# jquery callback на вызов события

Tags: jquery

Есть обычный input на которое висит событие change

```
$("input").change(function () {
 ...
});
```

Далее в ходе работы необходимо вызвать событие change.

Делаю так: `$("input").change();`

Стоит такая задачу, нужно вывести алерт, по окончанию этого события.
Только в сам обработчик ничего не писать. Как это можно реализовать?

Можно как-то передать коллбэк функию? Нужно что бы обработчик события остался неизменным, но когда я сам вызываю его, что бы запускался алерт?

Comment: в общем случае - это не возможно. Все зависит от того, что именно происходит внутри функции `change`. Вполне возможно указанного вызова вполне хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте триггеры для вызова обработчика события и передавайте в них какую-нибудь обозначающую переменную:

```
$("input").trigger("change", true);
```

пример:

```js
$("input").change(function (e, flag) {
    if(flag) {
        alert("button change");
        return;
    }

    alert("key change");
    // code///
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input>

<button onclick="$('input').trigger('change', true)">trigger</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Для начала лучше запускать событие change c помощью функции triggerHandler,а потом отлавливать его выполнение и совершать необходимые действия.

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $.when(
      $("input").triggerHandler("change")
    ).done(function() {
      alert('change done');
    });
  });
  
  $('input').change(function(){
      alert('input change trigger');
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>Run trigger</button>
```

Comment: если убрать `when`,`done` будет то же самое

Comment: alert убивает асинхронность.

Comment: проблема не в алерте: [_Instead of returning the jQuery object (to allow chaining), .triggerHandler() returns whatever value was returned by the last handler it caused to be executed. If no handlers are triggered, it returns undefined_](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/)